# Magento-2 : How to make customer email as optional to login

Tags: magento2, customer, email

I have custom extension, customer can login by mobile number with OTP, no need to email field as required to login.

I want to make an email address as optional.

How can I make an email address as optional?

Please suggest to me to achieve this requirement.

Comment: If you looking for extension then check it https://magecomp.com/magento-2-mobile-login.html

Comment: I have for login with mobile number, but I need to email as optional field. How can I make it?